# How to filter items inside CQWP, based on Content type + People/ Group site column

Tags: development, web-part, search, content-query-web-part, caml

I am working on a Team Site collection inside SharePoint 2013. and i want to display items that have specific content type + a people or group site column matches the login user. so i did the following steps:-

1- I Add a Content Query web part.

2- I Export the web part.

3- I Edit the web part's `QueryOverride` tag.

4- i specfiy the following:- here is the full web part content (where i have just edit the QueryOverride tag).:-

```
    <webParts>
      <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
        <metaData>
          <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
          <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
        </metaData>
        <data>
          <properties>
            <property name="Filter1ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Or</property>
            <property name="FilterOperator1" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
            <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
            <property name="FilterOperator3" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
            <property name="GroupByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
            <property name="DataSourceID" type="string" />
            <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
            <property name="SystemViewFields" type="string" />
            <property name="ListName" type="string" />
            <property name="FilterDisplayValue3" type="string" />
            <property name="FilterDisplayValue2" type="string" />
            <property name="FilterDisplayValue1" type="string" />
            <property name="FilterField1" type="string" />
            <property name="Description" type="string">Displays a dynamic view of content from your site.</property>
            <property name="DataColumnRenames" type="string" />
            <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
            <property name="PageSize" type="int">-1</property>
            <property name="ViewContentTypeId" type="string" />
            <property name="ParameterBindings" type="string" />
            <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
            <property name="AdditionalFilterFields" type="string" />
            <property name="DataMappingViewFields" type="string">{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},Image;{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Text;{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69},DateTime;</property>
            <property name="Title" type="string">B</property>
            <property name="FeedDescription" type="string" />
            <property name="UseCache" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="XslLink" type="string" null="true" />
            <property name="AutoRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="Filter1IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="FilterValue3" type="string" />
            <property name="SortByFieldType" type="string">DateTime</property>
            <property name="ManualRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
            <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="ItemStyle" type="string">NoImage</property>
            <property name="SampleData" type="string">&lt;dsQueryResponse&gt;
                        &lt;Rows&gt;
                            &lt;Row Title="Item 1" LinkUrl="http://Item1" Group="Group Header" __begincolumn="True"
__begingroup="True" /&gt;
                            &lt;Row Title="Item 2" LinkUrl="http://Item2" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" /&gt;
                            &lt;Row Title="Item 3" LinkUrl="http://Item3" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" /&gt;
                        &lt;/Rows&gt;
                        &lt;/dsQueryResponse&gt;</property>
            <property name="FilterIncludeChildren2" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="XmlDefinitionLink" type="string" />
            <property name="ServerTemplate" type="string">1100</property>
            <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
            <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string" />
            <property name="QueryOverride" type="string" >
             <![CDATA[
            <Where>
      <Or>
         <And>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" /> <Value Type="ContentTypeId">0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18802</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="Technical_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" LookupId="TRUE" />
        <Value Type="Integer"><UserID /></Value>
            </Eq>
         </And>
         <And>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" /> <Value Type="ContentTypeId">0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18803</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="User_x0020_Support_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" LookupId="TRUE" />
        <Value Type="Integer"><UserID /></Value>
            </Eq>
         </And>
      </Or>
    </Where>]]>
            </property>
            <property name="DataSourcesString" type="string" />
            <property name="DisplayName" type="string" />
            <property name="ListGuid" type="string" />
            <property name="DataFields" type="string" />
            <property name="ShowWithSampleData" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="GroupByFieldType" type="string" />
            <property name="Default" type="string" />
            <property name="ViewFlags" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewFlags, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">None</property>
            <property name="ContentTypeBeginsWithId" type="string" />
            <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="FeedEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="SortBy" type="string">{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}</property>
            <property name="FilterByContextTerm" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
            <property name="PlayMediaInBrowser" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="ViewFlag" type="string">0</property>
            <property name="Xsl" type="string">&lt;xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3/Publishing/runtime" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl cmswrt x" &gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl" /&gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl" /&gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl" /&gt; &lt;/xsl:stylesheet&gt;</property>
            <property name="FilterField2" type="string" />
            <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
            <property name="CacheXslTimeOut" type="int">86400</property>
            <property name="AdditionalGroupAndSortFields" type="string" />
            <property name="UseSQLDataSourcePaging" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="Height" type="string" />
            <property name="DataMappings" type="string">Description:{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69},Created,DateTime;|ImageUrl:{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl,Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},PublishingRollupImage,Image;|Title:{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Title,Text;|LinkUrl:|</property>
            <property name="ListUrl" type="string" null="true" />
            <property name="ShowUntargetedItems" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="GroupBy" type="string" />
            <property name="FilterIncludeChildren1" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="BaseType" type="string" />
            <property name="MainXslLink" type="string" />
            <property name="AsyncRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="FilterValue1" type="string" />
            <property name="FilterValue2" type="string" />
            <property name="InitialAsyncDataFetch" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="AutoRefreshInterval" type="int">60</property>
            <property name="Filter3IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="GroupStyle" type="string">DefaultHeader</property>
            <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="FilterIncludeChildren3" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="EnableOriginalValue" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="ItemLimit" type="int">15</property>
            <property name="FilterType1" type="string" />
            <property name="UseCopyUtil" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="FilterType3" type="string" />
            <property name="FilterType2" type="string" />
            <property name="FilterOperator2" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
            <property name="PageType" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">PAGE_NORMALVIEW</property>
            <property name="FilterByAudience" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="ItemXslLink" type="string" />
            <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="WebUrl" type="string">~sitecollection</property>
            <property name="HeaderXslLink" type="string" />
            <property name="CacheXslStorage" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="ListsOverride" type="string" />
            <property name="SortByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
            <property name="Filter2IsCustomValue" type="bool">False</property>
            <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="FeedTitle" type="string" />
            <property name="FilterField3" type="string" />
            <property name="MediaPlayerStyleSource" type="string" null="true" />
            <property name="DisplayColumns" type="int">1</property>
            <property name="Filter2ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Or</property>
            <property name="XmlDefinition" type="string" />
            <property name="WebsOverride" type="string" />
            <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
            <property name="ContentTypeName" type="string" />
            <property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</property>
            <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
            <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" />
            <property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string" />
            <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
            <property name="ListDisplayName" type="string" null="true" />
            <property name="Width" type="string" />
          </properties>
        </data>
      </webPart>
    </webParts>
```

5- i add the web part to my web parts lists , then i edit a page and i add the web part, but i did not get any result. although i have many items that matches the query..

so can anyone adivce on this please ?
Thanks

Additional Info:-
i got the content type id from the URL , where i access the CT info from the UI and the url showed the following :-

```
_layouts/15/ManageContentType.aspx?ctype=0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18802
```

for the site columns i also access the column from the UI, and their internal name looks as follow:-

```
/_layouts/15/ManageContentTypeField.aspx?ctype=0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18802&Field=Technical%5Fx0020%5FDelivery%5Fx0020%5FTeam&Fid=%7B68bd4d83%2Ddbfa%2D4e0a%2Daf37%2D76c0a0056ae8%7D
```

**----EDIT------**

for testing purposes i wrote the following CAML where i define the CT names instead of ids , and it retrieved all the items that have any of these two CTs correctly:-

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Created"  Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="ContentType"/><Value Type="Computed">Business Functions Technical Delivery Risk Issue</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="ContentType"/><Value Type="Computed">Business Functions User Support Delivery Risk Issue</Value></Eq></Or></Where>]]></property>
```

now i changed my query to check if the login user = any of two site columns,, but this will not return any results un-like the above CAML query ? i am really confused on how CAML should work ? this is the most confusing topic i have every worked on in my whole life !!!

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Created"  Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="User_x0020_Support_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer" /></Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="Technical_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer" /></Value></Eq></Or></Where>]]></property>
```

**---EDIT 2 ---**

Now the only query i have it working correctly is this simple query :-

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Created"  Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="ContentType"/><Value Type="Computed">Business Functions Technical Delivery Risk Issue</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="ContentType"/><Value Type="Computed">Business Functions User Support Delivery Risk Issue</Value></Eq></Or></Where>]]></property>
```

but if i add inner `<And></And>` tags inside it , it will stop work , for example this will not work :-

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Created"  Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy><Where><Or><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="ContentType"/><Value Type="Computed">Business Functions Technical Delivery Risk Issue</Value></Eq></And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="ContentType"/><Value Type="Computed">Business Functions User Support Delivery Risk Issue</Value></Eq></And></Or></Where>]]></property>
```

but if i remove all the `<AND>` & `</And>` tags it will work well .. so can anyone adivce ?

Comment: Try with "contains" rather than "equal".

Comment: Replace <Eq> with <Contains> for both ContentTypeId field in QueryOverride property

Answer (score 1):

Try with `ContentTypeId` first and add `<Query>` before `<Where>` and with `Value Type="Text"`

```
    <property name="QueryOverride" type="string" >
             <![CDATA[
<Query>
    <Where>
      <Or>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" /> <Value Type="ContentTypeId">0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18802</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" /> <Value Type="ContentTypeId">0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18803</Value>
            </Eq>
      </Or>
    </Where>
</Query>]]>
            </property>
```

If you get results then add that Delivery Team fields.

**EDIT**

Try remove CDATA and replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`

...and replace `""` with `''`

So that you have something like this.

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Or&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /&gt; &lt;Value Type='ContentTypeId'&gt;0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18802&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /&gt; &lt;Value Type='ContentTypeId'&gt;0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18803&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Or&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;</property>
```

Add in property `CommonViewFields` your columns for ex. `ContentTypeId;Technical_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team;User_x0020_Support_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team`

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">ContentTypeId;Technical_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team;User_x0020_Support_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team</property>
```

list of internal names http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-internal-field-names.aspx

more on link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx

**EDIT 2**

Look at this pages

http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2011/11/cqwp-queryoverride-filter-data-based-on.html
http://blog.riccardocelesti.it/extend-content-query-web-part-with-queryoverride/

Try without spaces all in one line, replace `'` with `&quot;` and add CDATA

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Or&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentTypeId&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;ContentTypeId&quot;&gt;0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18802&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentTypeId&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;ContentTypeId&quot;&gt;0x01030039A425F609A70A44BA580AF4A69CB18803&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Or&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;]]></property>
```

Maybe you needed to write CDATA **just after QueryOverride without space**. Try it.

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<Where>...
```

Check your columns internal names

&Field=**Technical%5Fx0020%5FDelivery%5Fx0020%5FTeam**&Fid=%7B6..

**EDIT 3**

Open powershell as admin and run this script which will tell you internal name of site columns match title "Team"
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

```
$url = "http://YOURSITE"

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$web = $site.rootweb.Fields
ForEach ($id in $web)
{
$id | select Title, InternalName | where {$id.Hidden -eq $false} | where {$id.Title -match "Team"}
}
```

Comment: can you check my edit section please ?

Comment: ok i tried this "<property name="QueryOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Created"  Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="Technical%5Fx0020%5FDelivery%5Fx0020%5FTeam" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer" /></Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="User%5Fx0020%5FSupport%5Fx0020%5FDelivery%5Fx0020%5FTeam" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer" /></Value></Eq></Or></Where>]]></property>">> but will not work. i think i need to decode the internal names before using them inside my web part is this correct?

Comment: i have 2 site columns and i am providing the correct internal names for them as follow:- <property name="QueryOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Created"  Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="User_x0020_Support_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer" /></Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="Technical_x0020_Delivery_x0020_Team" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer" /></Value></Eq></Or></Where>]]></property> ,, where %5F will be translated as "_"

Comment: see my last edit

Comment: i am providing the correct site columns internal names,, i already check this script. can you check my "Edit 2 " section , where i got a simple query working ,, but if i use inner <AND> tags inside the <OR> it will stop working,, can u please check edit-2 section,, thanks. as i think the CAML syntax is the problem or not all options are supported in SP.. same as in the first problem, where referencing CT by their ids will not work, but referencing them using their display names worked well..

Comment: as i second check i run the power shell script and the site columns internal names are 100% correct...

Comment: can you check my Edit-2 section please ?